# Multidimensional array data formation Issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I Need to form a below structure:

```
    {
   "M1":"",
   "C1":{
      "plots1":[
         "2021-04-16",
         "2021-04-17",
         "2021-04-18",
      ],
      "plots2":[
         "00",
         "01",
         "02",
      ]
   },
   "data":{"A1":[{ "x":0,
            "y":0,
            "value":3830855},{
            "x":0,
            "y":1,},],"A2":[ {
            "x":0,
            "y":0,
            "value":227049,
         },
         {
            "x":0,
            "y":1,
            "value":271379,}]}
}
```

But when formulate **data** part I am getting issue . can some one help me to fix this one.Below I have attached my working stackblitz link.In that I have added my input response and steps I followed so far.Please help me.

LINK : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-service-sample-64gcpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple records for given key, you were overriding it everytime. Update your inner loop with following code.

```
for (const [reportKey, reportValue] of Object.entries(value)) {
        //  console.log(reportKey, reportValue);
        // this["reportKey"] = reportKey;
        if (
          reportKey.toUpperCase() != horizontal &&
          reportKey.toUpperCase() != vertical
        ) {
          // this["reportKey"] = this.getMetricsName(this["reportKey"]);
          let rK = this.getMetricsName(reportKey);
          // let dataSet = [];

          // dataSet.push(
          let dataset = {
            x: xAxis,
            y: yAxis,
            value: reportValue,
            "x-axis": horizontal,
            "y-axis": vertical,
            "x-name": value.PROCESSING_DAY,
            "y-name": value.PROCESSING_TIME
          };
          // );
          if (!(rK[0] in reportKeyData)) {
            reportKeyData[rK[0]] = [];
          }
          reportKeyData[rK[0]].push(dataset);
          // reportKeyData[this["reportKey"][0]] = dataSet;
        }
      }
```

Note: I've kept your code as commented, so you can see what has been changed.